# Sending and receiving package in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

This is a console chat app on a TCP socket server. The client will send the request/message to the server and the server will distribute the message to the target user or provide requested information.I am currently running into a problem regarding the recv package on the server side. I received the package and was able to print it out. However the system still give me a syntax error for some reason.

Thanks.

This is my client:

```
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys, struct
import pickle

HEADER_LENGTH = 1024
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9669

def send_login_request(username):
    package = [1]
    length = len(username)
    if length > 1019:
        print ("Error: Username too long")
        sys.exit()
    package += struct.pack("I", length)
    package += username
    
    return package

def send_message(recv_id, message):
    package = [2]
    length = len(message)
    if length > 1015:
        print('message too long')
        sys.exit()
    package += recv_id
    package += struct.pack('I', length)
    package += message
    return package

def send_con_request(conv_id):
    package = [3]
    length = len(id)
    if length > 1015:
        print('id too long')
        sys.exit()
    package += struct.pack("I", length)
    package += conv_id
    return package
# Create a socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to a given ip and port
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))

client_socket.setblocking(False)
my_username = input("Username: ")
request = send_login_request(my_username)
user_request = str(request)
client_socket.send(user_request.encode())
username_conf = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH).decode()
if username_conf == "Welcome to the server":
    con_id = input("Please enter conversation's id, if don't have one, please enter no ")
    if con_id == 'no':
        con_request = send_con_request(con_id)
        con_request = str(con_request)
        client_socket.send(con_request.encode())

    else: 
        con_request = send_con_request(con_id)
        con_request = str(con_request)
        client_socket.send(con_request.encode())

    conversation = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH).decode()

    recv_id = input("Please enter receiver's id")

    while True:
            # Wait for user to input a message

            message = input(f'{my_username} > ').encode()
            # If message is not empty - send it
            if message:

                send_message = send_message(recv_id,message)
                client_socket.send(bytes(send_message))

            try:

                while True:
                    message_receiver = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH).decode()
                    x = message_receiver.split('|')
                    print(x)
                    username = x[0]
                    message = x[1]
                    # Print message
                    print(f'{username} > {message}')

            except IOError as e:

                if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    print('Reading error: {}'.format(str(e)))
                    sys.exit()

                # We just did not receive anything
                continue

            except Exception as e:
                # Any other exception - something happened, exit
                print('Reading error: {}'.format(str(e)))
                sys.exit()
```

This is my server:

```
import socket
import select
import struct
import sys
import pickle

HEADER_LENGTH = 1024
conversation ={}
users = [
    {
        'username': 'user1',
        'user_id': 1
    },
    {
        'username': 'user2',
        'user_id': 2
    },
    {
        'username': 'user3',
        'user_id': 3
    },
    {
        'username': 'user4',
        'user_id': 4
    },
    {
        'username': 'user5',
        'user_id': 5
    }
]

def login(username):
    for user in users:
        if user['username'] == username:
            return user
        else: 
            return False
        

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9669

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))

server_socket.listen()

# List of sockets for select.select()
sockets_list = [server_socket]

# List of connected clients - socket as a key, user header and name as data
clients_socket = {}

sessions = {
    (1,2) : '1.txt',

    (3,4) : '2.txt'

}




def getRecvSocket(user_id):
    try:
        return sessions[user_id]
    except:
        return None

def sendErrorMes(socketid, mes):
    package = [9]
    length = len(mes)
    if length > 1019:
        length = 1019
    package += struct.pack("I", length)
    package += mes
    

print(f'Listening for connections on {IP}:{PORT}...')

# Handles message receiving

def receive_message(client_socket):

    try:
        receive_message = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
        return receive_message
    except:
        return False

while True:

    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)

    # Iterate over notified sockets
    for notified_socket in read_sockets:

        # If notified socket is a server socket - new connection, accept it
        if notified_socket == server_socket:

            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            
            sockets_list.append(client_socket)
            
        else:
        # Receive message
            
            package = receive_message(notified_socket)
            print(package)
            package_recv = eval(package.decode())
            print(package_recv)
            print(type(package_recv))
            package_type = package_recv[0]
            if package_type == 1:
                size = struct.unpack("I", package[1:5])
                if size[0] > 1019:
                    continue
                username = package[5:5+size[0]]
                username = username.decode()
                # username = package_recv[1]
                user = login(username)
                if user == False: 
                    notified_socket.send("no user found".encode())
                else: 
                    sessions[user["user_id"]] = notified_socket
                    notified_socket.send(("Welcome to the server").encode())
            elif package_type == 2:
                recv_id = struct.unpack("I", package[1:5])
                size = struct.unpack("I", package[5:9])
                if size[0] > 1015:
                    continue
                # recv_id = package_recv[1]
                if getRecvSocket(recv_id) == None:
                    sendErrorMes(notified_socket, "User is offline")
                else:
                    message = package[9:9+size[0]]
                    # message = package_recv[2]
                    for socket in sessions.values(): 
                        if socket == notified_socket: 
                            user = sessions[notified_socket]

                            # print(f'Received message from {user}, {message}')
            
                    # fIterate over connected clients and broadcast message
                    for client_socket in clients_socket:
                        # if clients[client_socket] == receive_user and client_socket != notified_socket:
                        # But don't sent it to sender
                        if client_socket != notified_socket and clients_socket[client_socket] == recv_id:

                            # Send user and message (both with their headers)
                            # We are reusing here message header sent by sender, and saved username header send by user when he connected
                            a = sessions[notified_socket]
                            b = recv_id 
                            with open(f"{conversation[a,b]}.txt", "w"):
                                f.write(user + message)


                            client_socket.send((user + "|" + message).encode())
                            
                    if message is False:
                        # print('Closed connection from: {}'.format(user))

                        # Remove from list for socket.socket()
                        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

                        # Remove from our list of users
                        del clients_socket[notified_socket]

                        continue
            
            elif package_type == 3: 
                size = struct.unpack("I", package[1:5])
                if size[0] > 1019:
                    continue
                convo_id = package[5:5+size[0]]
                convo_id = convo_id.decode()
                # convo_id = package_recv[2]
                if convo_id in conversation:
                    with open(conversation[convo_id], 'rb') as file_to_send:
                        for data in file_to_send:
                            notified_socket.sendall(data)
                    print('send successful')

                else: 
                    f = open(f"{len(conversation)+1}.txt", "w+")
```

This is the error in the server side which I am having a problem to locate and solve:

```
Listening for connections on 127.0.0.1:9669...
b"[1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 'u', 's', 'e', 'r', '1']"
[1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 'u', 's', 'e', 'r', '1']
<class 'list'>
b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Duong Dang/Desktop/bai 2.3/server.py", line 134, in <module>
    package_recv = eval(package.decode())
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sending code doesn't make a lot of sense. You're creating a python list which is a most strange way to implement a protocol. You're then taking python's string representation of that list and sending it to the server. You're not doing anything on the server side to ensure that you got the entire message. Then you're using `eval` to interpret the string you created on the client. That is a very dangerous practice, as your peer can essentially instruct your python interpreter to do literally anything.

Also, your `send_con_request` is calling `len(id)` which won't work at all because `id` is a python built-in that doesn't supply a `__len__` method. I assume that was supposed to be `len(conv_id)`?

Anyway, you should rework your protocol. Use the `struct` tools to create the correct binary string you want. There are tons of possible ways to structure this but here's one. On the client side, create a *fixed-length* header that identifies which request type you're sending and the length of the remaining "payload" bytes. You'll convert your string (username or whatever) into bytes first with `str.encode`.

```
import struct

# ProtoHeader encodes a 16 bit request identifer, plus a 32 bit payload
# length. A protocol data unit consists of this 6-byte header followed by 
# payload bytes (which will vary according to the request)
ProtoHeader = struct.Struct("!HI")

LoginRequest = 1
SomeOtherRequest = 2
...

def format_login_request(username):
    """ Create a protocol block containing a user login request.
        Return the byte string containing the encoded request """
    username_bytes = username.encode()
    proto_block = ProtoHeader.pack(LoginRequest, len(username_bytes)) + username_bytes
    return proto_block

...

conn.sendall(format_login_request(username))
```

On the server side, you will first receive the fixed-length header (which tells you what the request type was and how many other payload bytes are present). Then receive those remaining bytes ensuring that you get exactly that many. `socket.recv` does not guarantee that you will receive exactly the number of bytes sent in any particular `send` from the peer. It *does* guarantee that you will get them in the right order so you must keep receiving until you got exactly the number you expected. That's why it's important to have fixed length byte strings as a header and to encode the number of bytes expected in variable length payloads.

The server would look something like this:

```
import struct

ProtoHeader = struct.Struct("!HI")
LoginRequest = 1

def receive_bytes(conn, count):
    """ General purpose receiver:
        Receive exactly @count bytes from @conn """
    buf = b''
    remaining = count
    while remaining > 0:
        # Receive part or all of data
        tbuf = conn.recv(remaining)
        tbuf_len = len(tbuf)
        if tbuf_len == 0:
            # Really you probably want to return 0 here if buf is empty and
            # allow the higher-level routine to determine if the EOF is at
            # a proper message boundary in which case, you silently close the
            # connection. You would normally only raise an exception if you 
            # EOF in the *middle* of a message.
            raise RuntimeError("end of file")
        buf += tbuf
        remaining -= tbuf_len
    return buf

def receive_proto_block(conn):
    """ Receive the next protocol block from @conn. Return a tuple of
        request_type (integer) and payload (byte string) """

    proto_header = receive_bytes(conn, ProtoHeader.size)
    request_type, payload_length = ProtoHeader.unpack(proto_header)
    payload = receive_bytes(conn, payload_length)
    return request_type, payload

...

request_type, payload = receive_proto_block(conn)
if request_type == LoginRequest:
    username = payload.decode()
```